# Can I take a screenshot while i am using ACTION_VIEW service?

Tags: android, eclipse, dictionary, screenshot

(First of all, sorry about my english)
I'm callig map activity from my main activity by this way:

```
String coord="geo:0,0";     
Intent intent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(coord));
startActivityForResult(intent,2);
```

...and is working fine. By the other side, i have onActivityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int request,int result,Intent intent){
      //I think here should be the screenshot code
}
```

... which is called when the map activity finishes, and is also working fine. 
Now, what I need is to take a screenshot (image, bitmap or drawable, i don't mind) of the map view at the moment that the map activity is getting closed (The final map), and i dont know if it is posible.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot take a screenshot of another app, unless your app is running with superuser privileges and you use various undocumented techniques.

Second, by the time `onActivityResult()` is called, the map activity is not necessarily visible anymore.